# Can I stop the submitted statements on the first error?

Tags: error-handling, sas

Just for the debugging purpose: Is there a way to stop executing a series of submitted statements on the first error?

Let's say, I have three steps of code where the second statement has an error. Assume that I run all of them at once in the SAS window. Then, I expect SAS to successfully execute the first sentence and to stop working due to the error detected in the second sentence. Then I can easily go there to fix this.

But what's actually happening is that SAS tries to execute all three steps (i.e., 1st, 2nd (with error,  though), and 3th). Hope that there is a solution for this.

Two remarks:

1. I found that the below code may help, but it didn't actually. Otherwise, please enlighten me.

```
options syntaxcheck dmssynchk;
```

2. I don't want to use the SAS option, `errorabend` because it shuts down SAS session itself. I just want my SAS stop "the submitted code" and want to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a commonly used macro called `%runquit` that allows that... Not sure where it originates from, but here it goes:

```
%macro runquit;
  ; run; quit;
  %if &syserr. ne 0 %then %do;
     %abort cancel;
  %end;
%mend runquit;

proc sort data=asdasd;
 by _all_;
%runquit;

data abc;
 a = 1;
 b = 2;
 c = 3;
%runquit;
```

The drawback is that you have to replace any `run;` or `quit;` statement with the call to `%runquit`, making the code less pretty.

A related StackOverflow question can be found [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/errorabend-vs-runquit/td-p/255304).

Also, see [this discussion](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/errorabend-vs-runquit/td-p/255304) for other solutions.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for. But sounds like there is no option that was made by SAS. So I have to use this macro code made by somebody else. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Note: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.